# What is wrong with my CQL-filter

Tags: geotools

Im making a simple test with CQL in my GeoTools application. This is the first time I'm trying to use CQL, and I cant get it to work.

```
String filterText = "IN ('TIA.7','TIA.6','TIA.8','TIA.9','TIA.10','TIA.11','TIA.12','TIA.13')";
Filter filter = CQL.toFilter(filterText);
```

Then I get this error when executing CQL.toFilter...:

```
org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Expecting Filter Parsing : IN ('TIA.7','TIA.6','TIA.8','TIA.9','TIA.10','TIA.11','TIA.12','TIA.13')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about geotools, but shouldn't you include the fieldname to filter on? E.g. `filterText = "MyField in ('TIA.7', 'TIA.6', ... )"`

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the function to see what it is looking for?